# How to save email draft as Outlook Template .oft format?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to save an email draft in Outlook Template format (*.oft) in the folder "F:\Template\winword.2003"

```
Sub SendMultipleEmails()

    Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Object

    With OutApp
        .Subject = "My Acc Holding Holding")
        .Body = "Hello" & vbNewLine _
               & vbNewLine _
               & "Please find the attached Acc Holding"
        .Display
        bc = ws.Range("F" & i + 1).Value

        For j = first To i
            bc = bc & ";" & ws.Range("F" & j).Value
        Next
        .BCC = bc
        first = i + 2
        .Display
        .Close olSave
        first = i + 2
    End With

    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all You got 'End If' without 'If' and 'Next' without 'For' loop in the end of your code.

Comment: apology... its not entire code.

Comment: When you ask a question, the code should be complete enough to run/test with. See the concept [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an email as Template to your hard drive, you can use the Outlook `.Save` function:

```
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olTemplate
```

Where `sPath` is your path and `sName` is your filename.

In your code should be something like this:

```
Sub SendMultipleEmails()
    Dim OutMail, OutApp As Object
    Dim sPath As String, sName As String
    sPath = "F:\Template\winword.2003\"
    sName = "myTemplate.oft"

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

    With OutMail
         .Subject = "My Acc Holding Holding"
         .Body = "Hello" & vbNewLine _
                & vbNewLine _
                & "Please find the attached Acc Holding"

         bc = ws.Range("F" & i + 1).Value

        For j = first To i
           bc = bc & ";" & ws.Range("F" & j).Value
        Next

        .BCC = bc
        first = i + 2

        .Display
        .SaveAs sPath & sName, olTemplate
        .Close olSave
        first = i + 2
    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Getting Runtime Error, application-defined or object- defined error

Comment: Yes, because it was missing object initializzation. Try now (ofc I can't guarantee for the rest of your code, since it's incomplete).